# How to change the class of the active element of navigation bar in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navigationbar

I want to change the class of the navigation bar element when on clicked. Should I use `v-bind` or `v-on` in this kind of instance? I want to Create a function and bind it to the onclick and dd logic to change active menu item

Here's the code for the navigationBarMenu.vue component that I am writing.

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        //  Change the names to the correct names
        {
          name: 'Features',
          url: '/features'
        },
        {
          name: 'Prices',
          url: '/prices'
        },
        {
          name: 'Community',
          url: '/community'
        },
        {
          name: 'Support',
          url: '/support'
        }
      ]

    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectMenuItem: function (id) {
      this.activeId = id;
    }
  }


}
</script>
<template>


  <!-- Create an array and render the items -->
  <!-- Create a function and bind it to the onclick. Add logic to change active menu item  -->
  <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ item.url }}" 
    v-on:click="setActive()" :class="{ active:isActive('item.index') }">

    <!-- <a v-bind:class"{ active: (item.index == activeId) }" href="{{ item.url }}" v-on:click="selectMenuItem(item.index)"> -->
      {{ item.name }}
      
    </a>

  </li>




</template>
```

Comment: You should be using [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) for this

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that I came up with. in `AppHeaderMenu.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        //  Change the names to the correct names
        {
          name: 'Home',
          url: '/home'
        },
        {
          name: 'About',
          url: '/about'
        },
        {
          name: 'Speakers',
          url: '/speakers'
        },
        {
          name: 'Contact',
          url: '/contact'
        }
      ],
      activeItem: -1

    }

  },

  methods: {
    clickHandler(idx) {
      this.activeItem = idx
    }
  }

}
</script>
<template>


  <!-- Create an array and render the items -->
  <!-- Create a function and bind it to the onclick. Add logic to change active menu item  -->
  <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :class="{ active: index == activeItem }"
    @click="clickHandler(index)">

    <div>
      <a class="nav-link" :href="item.url">{{ item.name }}</a>
    </div>


  </li>




</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).